# Mistakenly tried to remove drain fixture in bathtub. How to ensure it is still sealed?

Tags: drain, bathtub

I wanted to clean the drain of a bathtub which has not been thoroughly cleaned for about 15-20 years. I thought that by loosening the drain fixture I can remove it and get better access to the pipe. However after loosening the screw and several turns later I realized that turning the screw has no effect. After doing some reading apparently you should never loosen this screw as it hold the siphon. I tried to tighten the screw again, but the screw does not pull. I also tried pulling the siphon up with wire and pressing the fixture onto it and tighten the screw without success. When I move the fixture I see that the siphon below moves too, so it seems that the fixture is still connected to the siphon. However I see the seal is a bit lower on one side.

How can I be sure that the seal is still tight?
What are tips to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Are you in a house that you own and have access to the room below the tub, so that you can gain access to the under side of it?   If you have loosened a 20+ year old drain shoe you will probably need to replace it.  Sometimes can access from a panel in the bathroom or next room.

Comment: @jay613 No, it is an apartment in a tower building

Comment: You should call the building manager to handle this.